# TYPO3 FAL, files are missing, case sensative issue, how can I fix manually?

Tags: typo3, fal

I have case sensitive problems in TYPO3 v 8.7 LTS. System is sometimes mocking that a file is missing. The error message is

```
Oops, an error occurred!
File /archiv/ABCD.pdf does not exist.
```

Allthough the file is there. When I put the file in lowercase to fileadmin "abcd.pdf" than FAL isn't mocking around. But seems after a while it still is mocking. 
At least I am not understanding where the problem lies. Because even if ABCD.pdf is there and in the right place I get warnings.

I checked DB integrity several times. But still no luck. Afterwards delete the cache in INSTALL TOOL.

I found DB tables where files are stored. Is there a way, that I manually can update this tables and get rid of these error message?

Comment: In addition I found a flag in mount point on root page which points to that my system is ignoring case sensitive settings. Also I found a scheduler task, which clears FAL entries but it fails at the very beginning.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the checkbox "case sensitive" on the storage is equal to your file system.

Run the FAL index update scheduler task.
That should align the DB values again